# Why doesn't Automator service appear in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, applescript, automator

I'm trying to write an Automator service for iTunes so that I can immediately open a file from iTunes in VLC, so I don't have to do (show in finder, launch with other application, vlc).

I go to Automator, create a Service, in the top right dropdowns, I choose: "Service receives selected `audio files` in `any application`", and the script itself is just "Open Finder Items" with VLC.

However, the service doesn't appear. Not in finder, not in iTunes.. I'm very confused. Any thoughts what's going on? I tried restarting computer, restarting iTunes, all to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you set VLC to be the default app for these files so you just need to double click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to work in iTunes, you can try setting it up like this:

Service receives selected: `text` in: `iTunes`

Actions:

"Get Selected iTunes Tracks" - Get selected: `tracks`

"Open Finder items" - Open with: `VLC`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. For future reference, seem to have run into this really weird issue, where if I save an existing Service and change the 'receives selected' field, it won't appear. I had to make a new Service to get it to appear!